# Make Nginx Proxy only upgrade SignalR WebSocket connections in Docker Compose stack

Tags: docker, nginx, asp.net-core, docker-compose, signalr

Is there a way to only upgrade SignalR WebSocket connections in your `nginx.conf` file without duplicating a whole section?

ASP.NET Core is rejecting my SignalR connections when they're not upgraded, however I'm running an API on that ASP.NET Core project that won't accept POST Request with bodies when the requests have the header "Connection: "upgrade"".

My current solution is just to duplicate the "location" section in my `nginx.conf` file as you see below. Is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

My `nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://ui:80;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        }

        location /shopvac/signalr {
            proxy_pass http://shopvac:80;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            rewrite ^/shopvac/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        }

        location /shopvac {
            proxy_pass http://shopvac:80;
            rewrite ^/shopvac/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        }
    }
}
```

My `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  proxy:
  database:

volumes:
  database-data:

services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - ui
      - shopvac
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - proxy
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - "5432"
    networks:
      - database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=home-system
      - POSTGRES_USER=home-system
  ui:
    build:
      context: ./ui
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "80"
    networks:
      - proxy
  shopvac:
    build:
      context: ./shopvac
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - /app
    expose:
      - "8080"
    networks:
      - proxy
      - database
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution!

So you can edit the "proxy_set_header Connection" property in `nginx.conf` to pass the necessary value forward.

The important section of the `nginx.conf` is now as follows:

```
location /shopvac {
    proxy_pass http://shopvac:80;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    rewrite ^/shopvac/(.*)$ /$1 break;
}
```